# Does a matrix need to be rationalized when calculating MatrixExp?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a sparse matrix, `L`, and need to calculate its exponential, `MatrixExp[L t]`, where `t` is a parameter.

When entries in `L` are  decimal numbers, calculation is pretty fast. But, when I rationalize `L`, calculation goes on and on. Is this normal behaviour? I'm working in *Mathematica* 10.

Remark: `L` is not normal matrix.

Comment: It might take a long time, depending on how complicated are the entries of its Jordan decomposition.

Comment: But, why this difference in regard of entries: decimal numbers vs rationalized?

Comment: Because the algorithms for exponentiation are different for inexact numbers and exact numbers.

Comment: Ok. But, answer for decimal entries is a reliable an, I guess? Or, in other words, there is no  room for doubt that result which mathematica gives is incorrect?

Comment: Depends on the matrix. Well, you did say your matrix is not normal, so the the guarantees are not as good as in the normal case.

Comment: But, what you can try is to compute it at two or three different levels of precision. Agreement in those results might mean your numbers are good.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I am going to try that route.